# How to save PHP file in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I did it like this in WordPress:

```
Appearance → Editor → Footer.php
```

How do I save the edits?

Comment: [Refer](http://wordpress.org/support/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a Update File button below the textarea where you edit. If you dont have the button it means your theme files do not have the permissions to edit.

Comment: You are right , I didn't had access permission as admin.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Save button on the left, just below editor window.